# How to make cartoonish fire wing effect?

Tags: fire, toon-shading

I would like to create a visual effect similar to [this one](https://pikbest.com/video/qianku-cool-flame-wings-burning-animation-transparent-channel-video_2447266.html). Basically, I need an animation of a flaming wing and the fire must dissolve in the ending.

[image]

I have tried to mix many different tutorials like fire mesh animations and cartoon explosions, like this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m0JkeK4m8E&ab_channel=IdowhatIwant) and this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE-uDqBpXxI&ab_channel=CodyWinch) but the results are way too far from what I really need. Does anybody have any tips or ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder if it won't be easier with Grease Pencil than with procedural texture

Comment: thank you! I I agree with you, just realized that it will be ueasier if I get a reference and make a frame by frame animation! ^_^